# How to sort users in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In laravel 5.2, I want to get users by order `country`, then `posts_count` and then `images_count`. For that I have used below query.

```
User::with(['profiles' => function($query) use ($country){
       $query->orderBy(DB::raw('case when country="'.$country.'" then 1 else 2 end'))->orderBy('country', 'ASC');
                        }])
      ->withCount('posts')
      ->withCount('images')
      ->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc')
      ->orderBy('images_count', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

But this query sort users by `posts_count`, then `images_count` and then `country`.
Please guide how can I fix the order priority `country` first in the query.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
User::with(['profiles' => function($query) use ($country){
                               $query->orderBy(DB::raw('case when country="'.$country.'" then 1 else 2 end'));
                        }])
                      ->withCount('posts')
                      ->withCount('images')
                      ->orderBy('country', 'ASC')
                      ->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc')
                      ->orderBy('images_count', 'desc')
                      ->get();
```

different way

```
DB::table('user')->select(DB::raw("(case when country!='".$country."' then 1 else 2 end)as country"),DB::raw("(count(post))as post"),DB::raw("(count(images))as images"))
      ->orderBy('country', 'ASC')
      ->orderBy('posts', 'desc')
      ->orderBy('images', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

Comment: This has not worked. This has thrown a error `Unknown column 'country' in 'order clause' `

Comment: do want different method for this

Comment: 2nd method is also not working. Because in the second method you have considered single table. I have User table which has relation with Profile Table, Posts Table, Images Table. This method has thrown unknown column errors.

Comment: We can do that in this also

Comment: I tried this suggestion with the help of https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries
But I did not get any idea how to solve this using relationship table.